# How to set onbeforeunload of a frame window inside the webpage loaded in WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, iframe, webbrowser-control, onbeforeunload, mshtml

Some webpages that are loaded inside an iFrame of a webpage that is loaded in `WebBrowser` component have a confirmation window pop-up when closing the webpage. This confirmation windows is preventing the main webpage to close, so I have to click on the option to leave the page. I would like to avoid this by altering `onbeforeunload` event of a webpage that is loaded inside an iFrame.

I have tried to modify [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883076/how-to-intercept-the-onbeforeunload-event-in-a-webbrowser-control) and apply it to my case. However, it appears that the solution applies only when accessing the event of a page that is loaded inside `WebBrowser`, not of an iFrame inside of it.

So here's what I have tried.

I have first declared the interface from the solution mentioned above:

```
[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface IDispatch
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetTypeInfoCount(out int Count);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetTypeInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iTInfo,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int lcid,
        out ITypeInfo typeInfo
    );

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIDsOfNames(
        ref Guid riid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] rgsNames,
        int cNames,
        int lcid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] rgDispId
    );

    [PreserveSig]
    int Invoke(
        int dispIdMember,
        ref Guid riid,
        uint lcid,
        ushort wFlags,
        ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DISPPARAMS pDispParams,
        out object pVarResult,
        ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo,
        IntPtr[] pArgErr
    );
}
```

Then, I want to set `onbeforeunload` event to `null` or somehow erase the contents of it, so that the pop-up does not... pop-up.

```
HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser2.Document.DomDocument;

// iFrame's id is "iF".
HTMLFrameElement frame = (HTMLFrameElement)document.getElementById("iF");
IHTMLWindow2 window = frame.contentWindow;

// Everything works fine until the following line.
var event = (ExtendedWebBrowser.IDispatch)window.onbeforeunload;

// Although no exception is thrown, event variable is always null, no matter if the webpage in the iFrame has or does not have onbeforeunload event specified.
// Setting the event to null does nothing. I'd have to come up with how to read this event before trying to set it to something.
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

So my final question is: **how can I get and set onbeforeunload event (or any other event, for that matter) of a webpage that is loaded inside an iFrame of the webpage loaded in WebBrowser control?**

Feel free to ask for any further explanation. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

**Further explanation of application routine.**

The application is sequentially navigating to the list of webpages. After each page is processed, it needs to be closed, and the next one loaded. Every webpage has an iframe which in turn loads the webpage from a different domain. I'm having no problems with the application whatsoever, except in cases when the webpage that is loaded inside the iframe calls `confirm` or `popup` in its `onbeforeunload` event. The confirmation pop-up box is preventing the application to process further webpages. I need to get rid of this pop-up confirmation window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having troubles with popups popping up, i've included a solution for you, and if you want to disable/enable javascript on the client machine (or even just read/query if it is enabled/disabled) ive included that answer for you as well, here we go:

Which popup message do you want to disable? If it's the alert message, try this, obviously resolving the window or frame object to your particular needs, I’ve just assumed top-level document, but if you need an iframe you can access it using window.frames(0). for the first frame and so on... (re the JavaScript part)... here is some code, assuming WB is your webbrowser control...

```
WB.Document.parentWindow.execScript "window.alert = function () { };", "JScript"
```

However, in your case, since you want to disable print, just swap `.alert` for `.print`.

You must run the above code only after the entire page is done loading, i understand this is very difficult to do (and a full-proof version hasn't been published yet) however I have been doing it (full proof) for some time now, and you can gather hints on how to do this accurately if you read some of my previous answers labelled "webbrowser" and "webbrowser-control", but getting back to the question at hand, if you want to cancel the .confirm JavaScript message, just replace window.alert with window.confirm (of course, qualifying your window. object with the correct object to reach the document hierarchy you are working with). You can also disable the .print method with the above technique and the new IE9 .prompt method as well.

Here is a Constant String (declared in VB) that will get rid of the 4 popups, including the new IE9 popup. In addition, it will get rid of the onbeforeunload event, and it will do all these on every single page its run on. If you have frames, you don't need to run them in frames as well, just running in parent document is enough. Here (declared in VB6), the _ is just fo rline continuation I placed there to make it easier to read, the & is for string concatenation, and the ; in javascript just means consider what follows as another line of code. This way, you can run many lines of code (below, I think 5) in one physical line.

```
Public Const DEFAULT_JS_TO_RUN_AFTER_EACH_PAGE_LOAD As String = _
& "window.alert = function () { }; window.confirm = function () { }; " _
& "window.prompt = function () { }; window.print = function () { }; " _
& "window.onbeforeunload = function () { };"
```

If you want to disable JavaScript entirely, you can use the registry to do this, and you must make the registry change before the webbrowser control loads into memory, and every time you change it (on & off) you must reload the webbrowser control out and into memory (or just restart your application).

> The registry key is
>   \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\ - the keyname is 1400 and the value to disable it is
>   3, and to enable it is 0.

Of course, because there are 5 zones under the Zones key, you need to either change it for the active zone or for all zones to be sure. However, you really don't need to do this if all you want to do is supress js dialog popup messages.

Let me know how you go, and if I can help further.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that accessing HTMLWindow methods and properties is not allowed (UnauthorizedAccessException is being thrown) if the frame is loaded from the different host than that of the parent page. Of course, I tried accessing those after the document has been completed. Also, completely disabling JavaScript is not an option. I'm afraid this is the first time I've encountered the problem that simply cannot be solved. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević actually, you'll be pleased to know there are ways to overcome the cross frame security issue, I can show you how, since you are running the webbrowser control, you're allowed to and can override it, it involved using a typelib which exposes certain methods that may or may not be available natively in the language u are using (basically exposing some c/c++ methods which we can use to override the cross frame issue). Let me know if you're interested. This control is the only thing I'm an expert at, so I'm always glad to be able to help someone re webbrowser control problems.

Comment: Forgot to add, you'll be able to run window.onbeforeunload = function () {}; to disable all calls to onbeofreunload as well if you want to. Basically disabling that event.

Comment: May I ask what it is you're trying to do ie: what is the purpose of your application?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please check out the description of the application routine, I've added it to the question. I am familiar with invoking native methods, but I'm afraid I have no clue where to start when it comes to this problem.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević i've updated the answer with some additional details, and a new constant. However, for the TypeLib solution I'm talking about, have you heard of Edanmo's OLE interfaces & functions? He has a solution to this problem here, but it's in VB6, now you may already have access to this API, so won't need this TypeLib, but still, using this TypeLib will work for you regardless of the language you are using. Can convert from VB6 toVB.NET and then to C#. Here it is (on the top, called OLELIB): http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml

Comment: @NikolaMalešević take a look around the site if there is any code in vb.net for the iframe cross-site security issues, if you can't find the code there, then do a search on the net for that issue and the keyword olelib.tlb and the code written for this issue should pop up! If it doesn't, of course don't be afraid to hit me up and we'll do whatever it takes to get it done, figure it out.